# Can I change the language the game client uses?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I buy a German retail copy of diablo 3 can I still change it to English?

I doubt that English language pack is included with it,will it be downloaded upon the change?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can change the language. And yes, it downloads the extra files when you do (after restarting the game client).

I changed it to Spanish (I had it at 100% in English) to try it for you and it's now updating.

[image: Diablo updating]

I really wish it would've warned me because now I have to wait for it to reach *playable* before I can re launch it and change it back. I hope this answer prevents someone from doing it without knowing it.

Luckily, reverting back to English did not download anything additional.

[image]

If you want to change the language, you need to go to Account, and then select the desired language. This changes all text and spoken dialog in the game.

[image]

Comment: +1 for your pain and suffering.  Noone should have to wait and download twice on release day.  The community recognizes your sacrifice.  RIP, English Diablo 3 client.

Comment: I will update whether or not it re re downloads when I switch it back to English

Comment: Waiting for you to switch back to english to see if it keeps the English files on memory or have to download it again ;)

Comment: Sorry to hear you had to download the complete Spanish pack :/

Comment: @Arremer, it wasn't that bad. It only had to reach "playable state"

Comment: Just had to "wait" for my language package as well. On OSX at least you can do `rm /Users/Shared/Battle.net/Agent/Agent.dat` and `rm /Users/Shared/Battle.net/Agent/agent.db` to reset to English again. Under Windows it will be buried within the registry.

Comment: I bought mine in Brazil. Although I changed the language of the game to english (like this answer pointed), I can not log in to battle.net from D3; the error is that my game client language does not matches the language of my bought game (which is defined by my cd key). So I can not play in english anyway! SAD! Very very sad!

Comment: That's strange @Girardi, you should be able to select any language and even region to play in. Feel free to ask a new question stating the exact error message and we'll see if we can help you

Comment: @JQAn: here you go -- http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75583/cant-play-diablo-3-in-different-language-why