# Diablo 3 English install with french key?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the language the game client uses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66164/can-i-change-the-language-the-game-client-uses)

I've installed an english version from a friend to play guest.

Now all that's available in stores are french version. Can I use the french key to play in english?

Comment: Do you mean your friend gave you a weekend pass?  Also, have you considered buying the digital version?

Answer (score 0):

Keys are bound to regions (EU/US) not languages.

Once your key is bound to your battle.net account you can play without restrictions on any language you want as long as it belongs to the same region. You should also be able to download the game in another language from the battle.net website if you no longer want to play the english version.

As Ashel also explained in another answer, it is possible to play in other regions but in that case there are  some restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If the French Diablo 3 is like other language-locked versions, it will only allow you to play with the French client.

Blizzard did not mention language-locked versions so I am currently stuck playing Diablo 3 in Korean. More info [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5151715654?page=1).

Comment: The topic you linked to was deleted :S

Answer (score 0):

Iirc I bought the digital version of  the game via Battle.net and I am pretty sure I did not need to specify any language at that point. If you want to play the game in a different language you need to download and install the game client again. To choose a different language to download the client  do the following steps:

- log into your battle.net account
- go to ACCOUNT
- choose `Download game client` under the `Games & Codes` section
- click on `change` besides the currently selected game client language
- choose new language to download and click `SAVE`
- then download your client, reinstall and have fun

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as others mentioned, the keys are region specific, not language specific. So you can buy any European key and you're fine to play in Europe.

As for the language, you **do not** have to redownload the whole game, if it's still installed.

Before logging in to your account, go to the options. There's a language dropdown box allowing you to pick your desired language. Once you've changed the language, the game will restart and download the language files (unless they're installed already).

Answer (score -1):

With the [Global Play](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-global-play-faq) system, you'll be able to play in any region regardless of your key's home location; though characters, items, and friend lists do not transfer across regions. Additionally, you won't be able to access the RMAH for another region, as it's only available in your home region. If you think the RMAH might be important to you, consider purchasing digitally with a NA battle.net account.

Comment: It 's not the region he's asking, but the language..