# How does region/language locking work for Legacy of the Void?

Tags: battle.net, region-lock, starcraft-2

If I buy a StarCraft 2: Legacy of the Void Battle.net key from a Russian shop, which says it's for "a Russian-language version, intended for activation in Russia", what are the restrictions exactly?

1. Does this mean that if I install an English-language version and log in with a battle.net account that has the Russian key it will not play?
2. Does it mean I need to have a Russian IP address when adding the key to my battle.net account?
3. Does it mean I need to have a Russian IP address whenever I'm playing the game?

I found [this relevant question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68384/diablo-3-english-install-with-french-key) about Diablo 3, but the answers are conflicting and anyway things may be different for Legacy of the Void.

Comment: Which shop you are referring to? As far as I recall, all game-related restrictions have been lifted sometime during WoL (i.e. multiplayer is played in the general European pool). There may still be a language lock, though.

Comment: It looks like resellers charge just a bit under the official Blizzard's price of 1499 rub., which means this is the full version. I've bought this same version from Blizzard, and I happily play in English.

Comment: ...and I've bought WoL for Europe for 60 EUR back in the day.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it can be bought for 1285 RUB, but I'd rather just buy from Blizzard for 1499 RUB. That's still about half the price they offer to most of Europe (40 EUR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no region locking anymore. There was a special discounted Russian version during Wings of Liberty, and even those were upgraded to full European at some point.

During HotS launch, people were also wary to buy cross-region upgrades (like having WoL for US, and HotS for South-East Asia), but it all worked out. Game licenses are global, and game profiles are per-region, but you can create a profile in each region you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy the cheap RU/CIS cd-key you CAN change the game region (i.e you can play on EU, NA and KR) but you can NOT change the Russian language of the game (i.e. all voices and text are in Russian).