# How much will I have to download if I change languages?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm a little short on bandwidth this month, and I'm thinking from switching my language from French to English.

Of what I know about multilingual games, I'll have to redownload the files of the language I chose.

So big are these files? And if I switch back to french, will I have to redownload the french files, or will the game have kept the french files somewhere?

Comment: I can't tell you how much the download will be, but if you are switching back to a language pack that has previously been installed, then you don't need to redownload. It wouldn't make sense that way. I played WoW in English, then I got bored and switched to French. Played that for a few months, got bored and switched back to English. It took some time to configure, but no visible download took place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer to the question,  [Can I change the language the game client uses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66164/can-i-change-the-language-the-game-client-uses), it appears to be roughly 2.5 GB. The answer-er also states that they didn't have to download anything additional when reverting to English, so I assume it keeps the language files.

Comment: So woops my question is duplicate.

Comment: @Fredy31 It isn't. Two questions that are different can have similar answers.

Comment: Have you tested this? Because, in my case, it downloaded almost 4.4 GBs for the playable level. The least amount is, when it just downloads the necessary stuff and the rest will download as you play, which will still download.

Comment: @Bora As you can see in this image(http://i.stack.imgur.com/zgBbf.png), the amount downloaded is 92 MB while the client itself shows 5.74GB of 8.29 GB is downloaded, so it is only downloaded the needed language files.

Comment: @Bora Blizzard also confirms this: http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-language-selection

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to "change" language in Diablo 3 without hassle, as in most of Blizzard's latest games, as in.

#### In game

This requires the least data download, since it only downloads the necessary language files.

Go to Options -> Account

Choose a language from the dropdown. The launcher will start and download the missing language files automatically.

#### Manually

This is clearly the long road, since it requires you to download the whole stuff in any particular language.

You will have to download the appropriate client from Battle.Net, to which you have access from your account. All EU accounts should have access to english, though.
Then you will have to uninstall the game and install the new client.

Log in to your Battle.Net and check out the [downloads](https://eu.battle.net/account/download/) section.

The download will set you back about **7 GB** and will per default not overwrite other downloads, since it has the locale code in its directory name: e.g. `Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer`

Here is what my account looks like:
[image]

Comment: Wrong: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66164/can-i-change-the-language-the-game-client-uses

Comment: Well the updater downloads the whole installer package itself, which is still 7 to 8 GBs. It's just the more comfortable way. I'll update my answer.

Comment: No it doesn't, it only downloads the needed language files.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just downloaded the German files and it took about 2.8 GBs. About 4 GBs for playable, though. Updated my answer accordingly.