# Can't play Diablo 3 in different language. Why?

Tags: diablo-iii

As suggested in another [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66164/can-i-change-the-language-the-game-client-uses#comment104521_66167), I'm asking this here.

I tried the procedure pointed out in the referred question, but then when I try to log in to Battle.Net from the Diablo 3 game, I get the following error message:

> The client does not match the account's native language. Please use the game's original client. (error 81)

I bought my copy of Diablo 3 in Brazil. I think that this is the problem: I can only download the Brazilian Portuguese game client from Battle.net website. Other languages are not available for me to download, even though I use my battle.net account in english.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. You'd think that in this day and age that a specific CD or something wouldn't be linked to a language...

Comment: I seem to remember reading something about it being possible earlier, and Blizzard changing it (supposedly) to stop people using cheap Russian keys. Don't have any reference or link though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blizzard announced that the retail versions of Diablo III would be locked to the region language, so if you bought yours in Brazil, your key is a Latin key and you'll only be able to play it in Brazilian Portuguese or Spanish.

Blizzard said that they made it this way in order to prevent what you did, to buy a cheaper game in another region (Brazil, Russia for example) and play the game in your natural language.

You can only choose your language freely in the special edition retail and the digital versions.

Here's an [article](http://www.kotaku.com.au/2012/06/error-82-blizzard-now-forcing-users-to-play-the-game-in-their-native-language/) that explains this further.

Comment: thanks! Well, I think that this is just sad. and Blizzard just did something wrong... But just a correction to your answer: here, in Brazil, things are actually more expensive than outside (taxes here are generally higher than 50%).

Comment: yeah, i know... i'm from Brazil too... the game is sold at the same price at the games stores and the digital version... so, the discount that Blizzard tried to give to us didn't reach our hands... this is pretty sad... and Blizzard really should do something about it... i really wanna play the game in english...